package dio_cache_interceptor doesn't make fetching data faster
I fetch data and I tried to use cache in order for my app to be faster if same data comes.
So I asked this question and get answer that I need to use package dio_cache_interceptor.
So I use it as below.

final cacheOptions = CacheOptions(
  // A default store is required for interceptor.
  store: MemCacheStore(),

  // All subsequent fields are optional.

  // Default.
  policy: CachePolicy.forceCache,
  // Returns a cached response on error but for statuses 401 & 403.
  // Also allows to return a cached response on network errors (e.g. offline usage).
  // Defaults to [null].
  hitCacheOnErrorExcept: [401, 403],
  // Overrides any HTTP directive to delete entry past this duration.
  // Useful only when origin server has no cache config or custom behaviour is desired.
  // Defaults to [null].
  maxStale: const Duration(days: 2),
  // Default. Allows 3 cache sets and ease cleanup.
  priority: CachePriority.high,
  // Default. Body and headers encryption with your own algorithm.
  cipher: null,
  // Default. Key builder to retrieve requests.
  keyBuilder: (request) {
    return request.uri.toString();
  },
  // Default. Allows to cache POST requests.
  // Overriding [keyBuilder] is strongly recommended when [true].
  allowPostMethod: true,
);

 Future<List> fetchTotalDiaries(
      UserProfile userProfile, int currentPage) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
        'user': userProfile.toJson(),
        'currentPage': currentPage,
        'offset': offset,
      };

      String requestBodyJson = jsonEncode(requestBody);
      final dio = Dio()
        ..interceptors.add(DioCacheInterceptor(options: cacheOptions));

      final response = await dio.post(
        "https://diejlcrtffmlsdyvcagq.supabase.co/functions/~~~",
        data: requestBodyJson,
        options: cacheOptions.copyWith(policy: CachePolicy.refresh).toOptions(),
        // headers: headers,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // final data = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.data));
        final data = response.data["data"];
        return data;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("fetchTotalDiaries --> $e");
    }

    return [];
  }

But after I fetch this data initially, I fetch this once again as data is not changed, it takes same time to fetch it.
My goal is to make it faster when I tried to fetch it once again and as I see Instagram, It works as I expected.
Please give me some advice on this.

Since you are specifying CachePolicy.refresh a request will always be made see. So that won't improve the performance. If your data is changing try to keep the cache valid for a shorter period of time (if it is okay to use an older version of the data). Also see here for some more documentation when there is no server side config.
